# Calculate most common string in a wxListBox

Tags: python, arrays, list, traversal

I have a wxListBox that is filled with strings (Customer Names) that the user inputs. I have to calculate the most occurring name and least occurring name in the list. I have to use a loop.

Below is actual code mixed with pseudo code, but I am having trouble with the logic:

```
cust_name = ""
for names in range(self.txtListBox.GetCount()):
    for compareName in counterList:
        if:
            names == compareName: 
            count += 1
        else:
            add names to counterList
            set count to 1
```

What is the best way to do this with a loop in Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) to count the names

```
from collections import Counter

names = ["foo","foo","foobar","foo","foobar","bar"]

c =  Counter(names).most_common() # returns a list of tuples from most common to least

most_com, least_com = c[0][0],c[-1][0] # get first which is most common and last which is least
print most_com,least_com
foo bar
```

Using a loop, just call `Counter.update`

```
c =  Counter()

for name in names:
    c.update(name)

c = c.most_common()
most_com, least_com = c[0][0],c[-1][0]
```

If you cannot import a module use a normal dict:

```
d = {}
for name in names:
    d.setdefault(name,0)
    d[name] += 1
print d
{'foobar': 2, 'foo': 3, 'bar': 1}
srt = sorted(d.items(),key=lambda x:x[1],reverse=True)
most_com,least_com = srt[0][0],srt[-1][0]
```

Comment: This would definitely be the easiest way, but I am supposed to be using a loop.

Comment: Awesome, appreciate it @Padraic

Comment: I am experiencing a TypeError: 'Int' object is not iterable in the "c.update(name)" line. I am using a wxListBox and not an array. Instead of "names" how could I call my wxListBox?

Comment: getCount  *Returns the number of items in the control.* so you just need to iterate over the items themselves.